# insert values from fixed number of rows to one row

Tags: t-sql, dynamic, sql-server-2008-r2, while-loop

SQL Server 2008 R2. Looking for straight ahead T-SQL code as a solution that I can implement. I understand conceptually procedural code using while loops and if then else, but I have not offcially written one line of t-sql code in a production environment. TIA

In order to complete a form, I want to convert up to six rows of data into one row of data, but never more than six rows of data are returned and inserted into one row of the other table. the reason (I believe) I want to do it this way is that the structure of the table into which I insert the values is already known so the 'price' of creating this table dynamically every time would be resource expensive. If that assumption is wrong, please correct me, but given the parameters here, the penalty for having a pre-existing table structure that gets filled in each time the form completion is invoked by the user, seems to be the way to go?

For example, let's say that the data returned from the query, which as stated can return up to six rows, here it has only returned five rows of data and they are:

```
Date1          Date2         Code#        Location      Who
08/22/2014    08/22/2014     1001      Los Angeles   Beethoven
08/22/2014    08/22/2014     1002      Munich        Brahms
08/22/2014    08/22/2014     1002      Hapsburg      Bruckner
08/22/2014    08/22/2014     1004      Vienna        Bach
08/22/2014    08/22/2014     1005      Los Angeles   Schoenberg
```

The column names in the table where the above values are to be inserted are:

Date11, Date12, ..... Date16, Date21, Date22, Date26, Code#1, Code#2.....Who5, Who6

In this example, the table being inserted into has a total of 30 columns. My 'real world' situation has a bit more columns, though, not a lot more. The number of (6X5) rows to be inserted into the (1x30) row, is variable and could be from one to quite a large number. These will be processed and then I will clear the table until next time the user asks to complete that form.

If the way in which I think I want to accomplish it is completely out of the realm of 'best practices' I am open to suggestion. But again if my approach isn't all that bad, I would love to see the t-sql while loop using the data from my example to accomplish it. Thanks so much, Stuart

Comment: We are not here to write code for you.  We are here to answer specific questions about errors.  Please do some research and give it a shot, and let us know.  You won't learn if we do it for you.

Comment: And why not to have `Date1` containing `'08/22/2014, 08/22/2014, 08/22/2014 ...'` and `Who` containing `Beethoven, Brams, Bruckner ...` - it would be a little less weird task then ... As you present it it seems to be quite out of the realm of best practices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     DECLARE @1billing int, @1sd1 date, @1sd2 date, @1location int, @1mod1 int, @1mod2 int, @1mod3 int, @1mod4 int, @1units int, @1amount money, @1cptcode varchar(64), @2billing int,
```

@2sd1 date, @2sd2 date, @2location int, @2mod1 int, @2mod2 int, @2mod3 int, @2mod4 int, @2units int, @2amount money, @2cptcode varchar(64), @3billing int, @3sd1 date, @3sd2 date, 
@3location int, @3mod1 int, @3mod2 int, @3mod3 int, @3mod4 int, @3units int, @3amount money, @3cptcode varchar(64), @4billing int, @4sd1 date, @4sd2 date, @4location int, 
@4mod1 int, @4mod2 int, @4mod3 int, @4mod4 int, @4units int, @4amount money, @4cptcode varchar(64), @5billing int, @5sd1 date, @5sd2 date, @5location int, @5mod1 int, @5mod2 int, 
@5mod3 int, @5mod4 int, @5units int, @5amount money, @5cptcode varchar(64), @6billing int, @6sd1 date, @6sd2 date, @6location int, @6mod1 int, @6mod2 int, @6mod3 int, @6mod4 int, 
@6units int, @6amount money, @6cptcode varchar(64) DECLARE HCFAcursor CURSOR FOR SELECT  dbo.[Billing Detail].Billing, dbo.[Billing Detail].[Service Date 1], 
                                                                                                                                                                     dbo.[Billing Detail].[Service Date 2], dbo.[Billing Detail].[Location Code], 
                                                                                                                                                                     dbo.[Billing Detail].[Modifier 1], dbo.[Billing Detail].[Modifier 2], 
                                                                                                                                                                     dbo.[Billing Detail].[Modifier 3], dbo.[Billing Detail].[Modifier 4], dbo.[Billing Detail].Units, 
                                                                                                                                                                     dbo.[Billing Detail].Extended, dbo.[Billing Detail].[Transaction Code]
                                                                                                                                                      FROM     [Billing Detail] INNER JOIN
                                                                                                                                                                     patient ON dbo.[Billing Detail].Chart = dbo.Patient.[Chart Number]
                                                                                                                                                      GROUP BY dbo.[Billing Detail].Billing, dbo.[Billing Detail].[Service Date 1], 
                                                                                                                                                                     dbo.[Billing Detail].[Service Date 2], dbo.[Billing Detail].[Location Code], 
                                                                                                                                                                     dbo.[Billing Detail].[Modifier 1], dbo.[Billing Detail].[Modifier 2], 
                                                                                                                                                                     dbo.[Billing Detail].[Modifier 3], dbo.[Billing Detail].[Modifier 4], dbo.[Billing Detail].Units, 
                                                                                                                                                                     dbo.[Billing Detail].Extended, dbo.[Billing Detail].[Transaction Code]
                                                                                                                                                      HAVING   (dbo.[Billing Detail].Billing = 2) AND 
                                                                                                                                                                     (dbo.[Billing Detail].[Service Date 1] = dbo.[Billing Detail].[Service Date 2]) 
                                                                                                                                                                     OPEN HCFAcursor FETCH next
FROM     HCFACursor
INTO       @1billing, @1sd1, @1sd2, @1location, @1mod1, @1mod2, @1mod3, @1mod4, @1units, @1amount, @1cptcode FETCH next
FROM     HCFACursor
INTO       @2billing, @2sd1, @2sd2, @2location, @2mod1, @2mod2, @2mod3, @2mod4, @2units, @2amount, @2cptcode FETCH next
FROM     HCFACursor
INTO       @3billing, @3sd1, @3sd2, @3location, @3mod1, @3mod2, @3mod3, @3mod4, @3units, @3amount, @3cptcode FETCH next
FROM     HCFACursor
INTO       @4billing, @4sd1, @4sd2, @4location, @4mod1, @2mod2, @4mod3, @4mod4, @4units, @4amount, @4cptcode FETCH next
FROM     HCFACursor
INTO       @5billing, @5sd1, @5sd2, @5location, @5mod1, @5mod2, @5mod3, @5mod4, @5units, @5amount, @5cptcode FETCH next
FROM     HCFACursor
INTO       @6billing, @6sd1, @6sd2, @6location, @6mod1, @6mod2, @6mod3, @6mod4, @6units, @6amount, @6cptcode
                   INSERT
                   INTO       [dbo].HCFALineitems(Item1Date1, Item1Date2, Item1POS, Item1Mod1, Item1Mod2, Item1Mod3, Item1Mod4, Item1Units, Item1Charge, item1cpt, Item2Date1, Item2Date2, 
                                  Item2POS, Item2Mod1, Item2Mod2, Item2Mod3, Item2Mod4, Item2Units, Item2Charge, item2cpt, Item3Date1, Item3Date2, Item3POS, Item3Mod1, Item3Mod2, Item3Mod3, 
                                  Item3Mod4, Item3Units, Item3Charge, item3cpt, Item4Date1, Item4Date2, Item4POS, Item4Mod1, Item4Mod2, Item4Mod3, Item4Mod4, Item4Units, Item4Charge, item4cpt, 
                                  Item5Date1, Item5Date2, Item5POS, Item5Mod1, Item5Mod2, Item5Mod3, Item5Mod4, Item5Units, Item5Charge, item5cpt, Item6Date1, Item6Date2, Item6POS, Item6Mod1, 
                                  Item6Mod2, Item6Mod3, Item6Mod4, Item6Units, Item6Charge, item6cpt)
VALUES  (@1sd1,@1sd2,@1location,@1mod1,@1mod2,@1mod3,@1mod4,@1units,@1amount,@1cptcode,@2sd1,@2sd2,@2location,@2mod1,@2mod2,@2mod3,@2mod4,@2units,@2amount,@2cptcode,@3sd1,@3sd2,@3location,@3mod1,@3mod2,@3mod3,@3mod4,@3units,@3amount,@3cptcode,@4sd1,@4sd2,@4location,@4mod1,@4mod2,@4mod3,@4mod4,@4units,@4amount,@4cptcode,@5sd1,@5sd2,@5location,@5mod1,@5mod2,@5mod3,@5mod4,@5units,@5amount,@5cptcode,@6sd1,@6sd2,@6location,@6mod1,@6mod2,@6mod3,@6mod4,@6units,@6amount,@6cptcode)
                CLOSE HCFAcursor DEALLOCATE HCFAcursor